# Centos 7 boot up with custom kernel problem

Tags: centos, kernel, linux-kernel, rpm

I have installed centos 7 on virtualbox machine which has kernel-3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64. I am trying to build Linux kernel from kernel sources. I downloaded the kernel source files from: http://vault.centos.org/7.0.1406/os/Source/SPackages/kernel-3.10.0-123.el7.src.rpm

I can build the kernel rpm successfully (using "`rpmbuild -ba kernel.spec`"). After that, I install the kernel rpm with no problems (using "rpm -Uvh").

However, when I reboot the system using the new kernel, it drops into to the dracut command line and gives the below warnings:

```
dracut-initqueue[207]: Warning: could not boot 
dracut-initqueue[207]: Warning: /dev/disk/by-uuid/58f6642f-bbb9-1479-b03c-e97156f66975 does not exist
```

System is not booting after this point.
I checked if `/dev/disk/bu-uuid/58f6642f-bbb9-1479-b03c-e97156f66975` really exists or not using blkid command and blkid doesn't return anything.

Why does `/dev/disk/by-uuid/58f6642f-bbb9-1479-b03c-e97156f66975` not exist? What am I missing?

Interestingly, if I download the kernel rpm (not the source) and install it, I can reboot the system with no problems. It's not stuck in dracut then.

Comment: Well, there is a "typo". It shoud be `by-uuid` not `bu-uuid`. Can you please double-check if this problem is on your grub file or just on your question ?

Comment: i checked but my problem is not based on grub file

Comment: I know is not a permanent solution, but what about you add the parameter `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true` inside `/etc/default/grub`, recreate your grub config file and edit the `/etc/fstab` changing the UUID partition to the direct path? - This is just a workaround so you can use your custom kernel while you search for more information about this dracut error